# How to add values together from a database in windows form application

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add all of a students course values together to get the average. The values are saved into a database but when I try add the values together and insert them into a text box it inserts both values into the text box instead of adding the values together.

```
            string output = "";
            output += (dr["Course 1"].ToString());
            output += (dr["Course 2"].ToString());
            txtbxaverage.Text = output;

        }
```

Comment: I could not understand what are you asking. Just to be clear; In their txtbxmarks.Text = ("Course 1:") + " " + (dr["Course 1"].ToString()) .. you just concatenated the strings. If you want to add them together, you should convert them to a number and add

Comment: Im trying to add values from a database together but when i insert it into the text box its inserting each value instead of adding the values together

Comment: ok then,  If you want to add them together, you should convert them to a number and then add

Comment: is Course 1 and Course 2 is int? and u want to add them

Comment: just convert this ((dr["Course 1"].ToString());) to decimal or interger then add the values into one variable

Comment: You might not understand that "+" is doing different things here.
"Tayla"+" "+"Brown" is string concatination and gives "Tayla Brown"
5+4 is addition and gives 9
Confusingly
"Tayla"+9 works and gives "Tayla9" (internally calling ToString() on 9 first)

You're mixing different types and unrelated operations

Comment: if you add strings together you are performing string concatenation you need to convert the result to primitives like decimal or int first ((decimal)dr["Course 1"])

Comment: I need to change the string to int? Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator "+" with strings is for concatenation, not addition. To keep it simple: "3" + "4" != "7", "3" + "4" = "34".

Now, if you want to calculate the sum of a series of string, what you can do is declare a variable started at 0, and add every string converted to int to that variable. Something like this:

```
int result = 0;
result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["Course 1"].ToString());
result += Convert.ToInt32(dr["Course 2"].ToString());
//And so on
```

Also, if dr is an array, instead of having a single line for each value in the array, you can iterate them all with a for or foreach loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dr.length; i++)
{
    result += Convert.ToInt32(dr[i].ToString());
}
```

And if dr is an array of integer or some other numeric type, you don't need to use ToString function. Do this instead:

```
result += dr[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add 2 strings together, it concatenations them together.

"Hello" + "_World" = "hello_World"

You want:

```
string output = "";
output += dr["Course 1"];
output += dr["Course 2"]);
txtbxaverage.Text = output.ToString();
```

You only call "ToString()"  AFTER adding the integers together.

Comment: You're still concatenating strings here, so the result will still be the same.

Comment: Ah sorry about that.  I incorrectly presumed   dr["Course 1"] was an int because OP was calling ToString().   Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Even if `dr[]` was an int, you'd still end up with a string because `output` is a string, so `output += dr[...]` will always be a string as `dr[...]` will be implicitly converted.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
txtbaverage.Text = $"{decimal.Parse(dr["Course 1"])+decimal.Parse(dr["Course 2"])}";
```

a string + string is equivalent to

```
"1" + "1" == "11"
```

a decimal + decimal equivalent to

```
1 + 1 == 2
```

so you need to convert for example

```
decimal.Parse("1") + decimal.Parse("1") == 2
```

doing a direct cast (decimal)dr["Course 1"] if the dr["Course 1"] is an object will convert it to a decimal then it can be added

Comment: I tried this but came up as an error saying "specified cast is not valid"?

Comment: Just explain this is related to boxing and unboxing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing explains this quite well but basically you need to get the values to be of the type that you can add whether that be int or decimal.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, using '+' with strings concatenates them, i.e. "Foo" + "Bar" will give you "FooBar". In your case what you need to do depends on the type that's stored in the `dr[]` array. If the array stores integers, you can simply add them directly, like so:

```
string output = "";
int sum = dr["Course 1"] + dr["Course 2"];
output = sum.ToString();
```

If the array stores floats or doubles it's the same, except you'd have to declare `sum` as the appropriate type.

If the array stores strings, you need to parse them before doing your sums, like this:

```
string output = "";
int sum = 0;
int value1, value2;
int.TryParse(dr["Course 1"], out value1);
int.TryParse(dr["Course 2"], out value2);
sum = value1 + value2;
output = sum.ToString();
```